# on change form submit variable value not updating

Tags: javascript, admin-menu, theme-options

I try to make custom theme option, a switch select option can change **$bannerchange** value. but i cannot add/update value of **$bannerchange**, select option inside a form. working fine with submit button but come to `onchange="this.form.submit()` the select option not changing.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['wphw_submit'])){
        wphw_opt();
}
function wphw_opt(){
    $bannerchange = $_POST['bannerchange'];
    if( get_option('bannerchange') != $bannerchange) {
        $chk = update_option( 'bannerchange', $bannerchange);
    }
}?>
  <form method="post" action="">         
   
        <select name="bannerchange" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <option value="page1"<?php if (get_option('bannerchange') == "page1") { echo " selected"; } ?>>Custom Departure</option>
            <option value="page2"<?php if (get_option('bannerchange')  == "page2") { echo " selected"; } ?>>Fixed Departure</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="wphw_submit" value="Save changes" class="button-primary" />
  </form><?php 
switch ($bannerchange) { 
    case 'page2': 
        break;
    case 'page1':
        break; 
}
```

**$bannerchange** get always undefined. I can debug this problem  with straight way? any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Change `<select name="wphw_submit"` into `<select name="bannerchange"`.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam not working

Comment: What's showing with `if(isset($_POST)) { var_dump($_POST['bannerchange']); exit(); }`?

Comment: not working undefined bannerchage.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam **$bannerchange** `null`

Comment: @MayeenulIslam thanks for your comments that's helped me much to finish my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed myself we can submit a form by triggering submit button click event:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#bannerchange').on('change', function() {
    var $form = jQuery(this).closest('form');
    $form.find('input[type=submit]').click();
  });
});
```